# Can't get ESP8266 to get JSON from the internet

Tags: json, api, get, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm developing with the NodeMCU's ESP8266 and have to get data from some JSONs on the internet. The thing is that, no matter what I try, I won't get anything back from doing the GET request, only a -1 error on the console.

```
void precioDolar (){
  serverPath = "https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales";
  jsonBuffer = httpGETRequest(serverPath.c_str());
  Serial.println(jsonBuffer);
  
  const size_t capacity = JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(9) + 2*JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(0) + 9*JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(1) + 2*JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(5) + 6*JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(7) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(10) + 590;
  DynamicJsonDocument JSON_Dolar(capacity);

  deserializeJson(JSON_Dolar, jsonBuffer);

  precioDolarOficial_Compra    =  JSON_Dolar["0"]["casa"]["compra"];
  precioDolarOficial_Venta     =  JSON_Dolar["0"]["casa"]["venta"];
}
```

If I print the `jsonBuffer` variable there's nothing on it, and I know for sure it has something to do with the `httpGETRequest` function not getting its job done.

This is the `httpGETRequest()` code:

```
  String httpGETRequest(const char* serverName) {
  HTTPClient http;
    
  // Your IP address with path or Domain name with URL path 
  http.begin(serverName);
  
  // Send HTTP POST request
  int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
  
  String payload = "{}"; 
  
  if (httpResponseCode>0) {
    Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    payload = http.getString();
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  // Free resources
  http.end();

  return payload;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: `"https://www.dolarsi.com` -> this is HTTPS rather than just HTTP. Hence, you need to set up a secure connection. https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino

Comment: @MarcelStör, the HttpClient should handle https

Comment: Not if you don't tell the client to either use an insecure connection or to verify using fingerprint, certificate, etc., no?

Comment: https in url is enough. web servers don't check client side certificates and esp has common CA certicates